# Issues starting up nginx with conf files

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean

I had setup my nginx server fine last week until I noticed I was receiving DOSS attacks against it. I then noticed at this point my Nginx server was failing to start. I have tried everything else and unsure what to do to resolve the issue apart from reading documentation which does not help.

Documentation on Nginx

main nginx.conf appears to be empty and I cannot save to it for some reason.

root@ubuntu-vpc-do-moon:~# /etc/init.d/nginx status
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-11-04 10:54:44 UTC; 1min 43s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 2550 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 04 10:54:44 ubuntu-vpc-do-moon systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Nov 04 10:54:44 ubuntu-vpc-do-moon nginx[2550]: nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:62
Nov 04 10:54:44 ubuntu-vpc-do-moon nginx[2550]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Nov 04 10:54:44 ubuntu-vpc-do-moon systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 04 10:54:44 ubuntu-vpc-do-moon systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 04 10:54:44 ubuntu-vpc-do-moon systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.

Comment: Resolved, removed nginx and done a new install and resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Removed Nginx from ubuntu and done a clean installation onto server. Managed to sort the server blocks out this time so all good.